# swapping between menus in python

Tags: python

How should I write this so I could constantly move between "menus".

```
 #!/bin/env python
  import os



class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self.menu = '1'

    def Main(self):

        os.system('clear')
        print "main menu"
        test = raw_input()
        if test == '2': 
            self.menu = '2'

    def Sub(self):

        os.system('clear')
        print "sub menu"
        test = raw_input()
        if test == '1': 
            self.menu = '1'


menu = Menu()

while menu.menu == '1':
    menu.Main()

while menu.menu == '2':
    menu.Sub()
```

At the moment I can swap once. ie I start with `menu.Main()`, enter '2' and `menu.Sub()` is shown. But then when I enter '1' the program quits. why does it not go back to showing menu `menu.Main()` ? Any thoughts welcome!

EDIT:

just needed to put them in a main while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first while loop runs, and when you enter '2', finishes. Therefore, the second while loop will begin to loop.

In the second while loop, you enter '1', which causes the second while loop to finish (because menu.menu is now == '1'). Thus, the program finishes.

Instead, you'll probably want one value for menu (that is neither '1' nor '2') to act as the exit state. For example, 'E'. Then, you can replace your two while loops with the following:

```
while menu.menu != 'E':
    menu.Do()
```

The "Do" method will handle the menu state if it's 1 or 2.

```
class Menu:
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu = '1'

    def Do(self):
        if self.menu == '1':
            self.Main()
        elif self.menu == '2':
            self.Sub()

    def Main(self):

        os.system('clear')
        print "main menu"
        test = raw_input()
        if test == '2': 
            self.menu = '2'

    def Sub(self):

        os.system('clear')
        print "sub menu"
        test = raw_input()
        if test == '1': 
            self.menu = '1'
```

You will still need to make it so that you can actually get to the 'E' case. I'll leave that as a task for you to finish.

Comment: i also just added `while 1:` to create a main loop... of course, For some reason as soon as I saw the wile loops I forgot that they needed to be in a main one themselves. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please keep the coding conventions when naming your classes and functions.

`modules` in python start with lowercase and usually do not include more a than a word, if it does it is separated by *underscore*. (e.g. `datetime`)

`Classes` in python start with uppercase and *CamelCased* for more than one word. (e.g. `MainClass`)

`functions` in python start with lowercase and separated with *underscore* (e.g. `keep_trying`)

I have been trying to read your code and misunderstood the code because of your style of naming. It is a bad practise for peer-reviewing, also bad practise for yourself as you will have hard time to understand the other codes.

--

To your question, if you follow the workflow you'll see that when you call `menu` you cannot call `sub` as your `if statement` only checks that if it is 1, not 2.

Here is a better way:

```
#!/bin/env python
import os



class Menu:

    def __init__(self):
        self.get_input()

    def get_input(self):
        input = raw_input()
        if input == '1':
            self.main()
        elif input == '2':
            self.sub()

    def main(self):   
        os.system('clear')
        print "main menu"
        self.get_input()

    def sub(self):
        os.system('clear')
        print "sub menu"
        self.get_input()


menu = Menu()
```

Comment: what is the difference between doing it this way and just doing what I did, but sticking it a main while loop? I will do my best to less offend people with my naming in the future...